# permission to create logfiles

Tags: python, django, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I´m trying to create logfiles in django 2.0.8. As long as i´m using it on localhost, the logfiles will be created and everything is fine. But when i´m running it on iis7, it won´t create the logfiles anymore. 
The Logfiles are created with python(3.6.5) logging.

manage.py:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('ProjektServer/logging.ini')
```

logging.ini_:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler, rotatingFileHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,rotatingFileHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=logging.StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_rotatingFileHandler]
class=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
args=(r'C:\log\project.log', 'a', 1000000, 3)
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

Afterwords it´s called like this in the pythonclasses for example:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
...
logger.info("ID is %d", int(shiftid))
```

I allready tried to follow the following instructions, thinking it is an permission problem:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

1. Open Windows Explorer
2. List item
3. Select a file or directory.
4. Right click the file and select Properties
5. Select the Security tab
6. Click the Edit button and then Add button
7. Click the Locations button and make sure that you select your computer.
8. Enter IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool in the Enter the object names to select: text box.
9. Click the Check Names button and click OK.

I also tried to run the website on the ISS with another Identity which is an Admin. But still no success. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Why do think that it’s a permissions error?

Comment: When I started to look into this, I only found this kind of explanation. When I showed this Problem to a friend, he also sad it´s a permission problem. What else could it be? I´m open for any other explanation.

Comment: It wouldn´t create the logfiles while using localhost, if there would be a problem with the settings. So the conclusion was that IIS perhaps didn´t had the permissions.

Comment: Are you sure that there’s actually a folder at the wanted location?

Comment: Yes, that´s the reason i set it to C:\log to make it easy to go around such errors and like I told localhost has no problems writing in the file. So it exists

Answer (score 0):

If the web application is doing impersonation, then you may need to add everyone that uses the application to be able to write to the folder, unless the logger is using the process account, or you revert to the process account before writing the log.  Add 'Everyone' to the folder permissions temporarily to see if it is a permissions issue.

Comment: Ok that didn´t work either. So the problem has to be somewhere else than the permissions...